# when i try to upload swf file I can't get $_POST data

Tags: php, html, file-upload

I have a simple html form like:

```
<form action="http://localhost/index.php" method="post" accept-charset="utf-8" enctype="multipart/form-data">
<input type="text" name="name"/> Name<br/><br/>
Content<br/>
<textarea name="content" style="width:350px;height: 350px;">

</textarea><br/>
Category: <select name="category">
        <option value="1">ABC</option>
        <option value="2">CBA</option>
    </select>
<br/>
Omage: <input type="file" name="image"/>
<br/>
Swf: <input type="file" name="swf"/><br/>
<input type="submit" value="Save"/>
</form>
```

If I select image when i upload file I can get data from $_POST like:

```
Array ( [name] => example [content] => try [category] => 1 )
```

But when i select .swf files the result:

```
Array ( )
```

What is the problem? How can i upload .swf file?

Comment: Then no files has been sent by the client

Comment: How large is the swf file?  If it's larger than your PHP configuration allows, $_POST might not get populated.

Comment: Yes @Kevin the problem originate for php.ini file. I have been edit and my problem solved.